# В чем отличие селекторов " " и ">"

Tags: css

Все привет!
В чем отличие селектора

```
.a > .b { color: #fff; }
```

от

```
.a .b { color: #fff; }
```

Comment: Только в весе! http://css.yoksel.ru/specifity/, https://habrahabr.ru/post/137588/

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko не только.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko стыдно не знать такое. https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 - здесь очень много тонкостей, которые мне в свое время помогли. Советую автору вопроса ознакомиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` распространяется только на непосредственных потомков элемента, а  (пробел) на любой уровень вложенности.

```css
.a > .b {background-color: #fcc;}
```

```html
<div class="a"><div class="c"><div class="b">Демо "&gt;" (фона нет)</div></div></div>
```

```css
.a .b {background-color: #fcc;}
```

```html
<div class="a"><div class="c"><div class="b">Демо "&nbsp;" (фон есть)</div></div></div>
```